# jQuery - Plugins and namespace issues with method chaining

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple plugin that I can call by both: `$.myPlugin()` and `$('something').myPlugin()`

Heres the code:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function(item) {
    return this;
  };

  $.myPlugin = function(item) {
    return $.fn.myPlugin(item);
  };
}(jQuery));
```

This works when called either way mentioned above.

However, calling `$.myPlugin().hide()` does **not** work. Any chained methods are failing.

[Heres a simple JSBin I made showing the issue](http://jsbin.com/ragozemana/2/edit?html,js,output)

Why?

Comment: `fn` is a shortcut for `prototype`, you're creating different instances and expecting them to somehow be the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `$(this)`, not jquery `this`:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myMethod = function() {
      this.append('<p>MY METHOD</p>');

      return $(this);
    };

    $.myMethod = function() {
      return $.fn.myMethod();
    };
}(jQuery));

$(function () {
    // Moment of truth
    $('.output').myMethod().hide('slow');

    $('h1').click(function(){
      $('.output').myMethod().hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "return element, not jquery function". I know it works fine by calling `$('.output').myMethod().hide()` but I want to be able to call it by `$.myMethod()`, similar to how you can do `$.each(item, function(){...})`

Comment: Then instead `return this;` use `return $('.output');` at 3rd line of you snippet